# get params in android and iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, android

```
?IMEI=i&CellId=c&LAC=Local_Area_Controller&NetId=i&ContId=i&Lat=l&Long=l
```

how to get all params above inside titanium application?

Comment: you have to use javascript function http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript. there is no specific functionality in titanium.

Comment: I need get IMEI of phone, LOngitude etc. I don't need to parse string above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the IMEI pragmatically via any of the official SDK methods.